# Passing Build Parameters from one Jenkins project to another Jenkins project

Tags: jenkins

How to pass build parameters from one project to another project?

Do we have any configuration in the Jenkins User interface which would pass build parameters of one build project after finishing it to another project?

I am able to trigger the other project but unable to pass build parameters. Do we have any scope of build parameters so that I can use it in all projects?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To do this, first install [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)

Then your first job configuration:

1. select "Trigger/call builds on other projects" under build.
2. give job name for "Projects to build"
3. select matching option under "Add Parameters".

I use "Predefined parameters" and in the filed, I  define like

```
 build.user.emailAddress=xxx.xx@yyy.zz
 build.user.id=abce
 mailPassWord=${mpWord}
```

Values set in those variable will be available for you in your second job selected under "Projects to build".

Comment: Kindly elaborate more so that I can understand it better.If possible please provide screenshots. Thanks in Advanced.Because I am uanble to see "Add Parameters anywhere I'm using latest version 1.597

Comment: You need the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) for what @Sreekanth described

Comment: Parameterized trigger lets you push parameters, what about pulling? Ex. Job A -> execute Job B , Job C ... can i pull parameters from B into A and pass them to C ? If i have a build job and a deploy job and i want a 3rd job to combine build-and-deploy ??

Comment: The link of the Parameterized Trigger Plugin is broken, see: https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-trigger/